# Go failed to call JavaScript function because buffer was introduced into JavaScript code

Tags: javascript, go

Go failed to call JavaScript function because the buffer was introduced into JavaScript code

**secret.js**

```js
import Buffer from 'buffer'

var Q = function(e) {
    return new Buffer("asdfl")
};
```

**main.go**

```golang
func main() {
    jsFile := "./secret.js"
    bytes, err := ioutil.ReadFile(jsFile)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    vm := otto.New()
    _, err = vm.Run(string(bytes))
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    enc, err := vm.Call("Q", nil, "123456")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(enc.String())
}
```

**error tips**

`(anonymous): Line 1:1 Unexpected reserved word`

Answer (score 1):

otto only implemented Javascript ES5 while `import` is a feautre of ES6, so you couldn't use `import` in your JS code.

update:
You can follow [this post](https://github.com/robertkrimen/otto/issues/349) to implement your own `require` method